# Finding Average Value of multiple attributes of a nested class using JAVA 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using the [fitbit Heart Rate API](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/heart-rate/#heart-rate-time-series) i wanted to find the average heart rate for each week over a period of 1 year. Java 8 Streams API was put in use but i am unable to figure out the best way to do it. My current implementation is not so efficient trial one for finding for the value for each month.
Would Spilterators be a best alternative implementation or is there any other way to make it more efficient ?

```
public class HeartRateService {

@Autowired
private FitbitRepository fitbitRepository;

public List<HeartRate> getHeartRateDetails() {

    List<HeartRate> heartRateResponse = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<Object, IntSummaryStatistics> results = fitbitRepository.getHeartRate().getActivitiesHeart().stream()
            .filter(hr-> hr.getValue().getRestingHeartRate() != 0)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(HeartRateActivity::getMonth, Collectors.summarizingInt(hr -> hr.getValue().getRestingHeartRate())));

    results.forEach((month,summary) -> {

        HeartRate hr= new HeartRate();
        hr.setMonth(month.toString());
        hr.setRestingHeartRate((int) summary.getAverage());
        heartRateResponse.add(hr);
            });

    return heartRateResponse;
}}
```

The class structure (POJO) for the Heart Rate API -

```
public class HeartRate {

@JsonProperty("activities-heart")
private List<HeartRateActivity> activitiesHeart;

public List<HeartRateActivity> getActivitiesHeart() {
    return activitiesHeart;
}

public void setActivitiesHeart(List<HeartRateActivity> activitiesHeart) {
    this.activitiesHeart = activitiesHeart;
}}

public class HeartRateActivity {

private String dateTime;
private HeartRateValue value;

public String getMonth() {
    return dateTime.substring(0, 7);
}}

public class HeartRateValue  {

private List<HeartRateZone> customHeartRateZones;
private List<HeartRateZone> heartRateZones;
private int restingHeartRate = 0;

}
```

- Setters and Getters are available for all attributes.

The Fitbit Payload structure can be viewed at [fitbit Heart Rate Time Series API](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/heart-rate/#heart-rate-time-series)

Thank You

Comment: where are `HeartRate` specific setters `setMonth` `setRestingHeartRate` etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the code in following way :

```
public List<HeartRate> getHeartRateDetails(HeartRate heartRate) {
    Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics> results = heartRate.getActivitiesHeart().stream()
            .filter(hr -> hr.getValue().getRestingHeartRate() != 0)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(HeartRateActivity::getMonth,
                    Collectors.summarizingInt(hr -> hr.getValue().getRestingHeartRate())));

    return results.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> computeHeartRatePerMonthStatistics(e.getKey(),e.getValue())) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

HeartRate computeHeartRatePerMonthStatistics(String month, IntSummaryStatistics statistics) {
    return new HeartRate();// convert to HeartRate given your inputs to method of conversion
}
```